# How to get custom value in laravel 5 custom validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have created a new custom validation in Laravel 5.0 like below to match the exact length validation. I have also setup the message for this in `validation.php`

```
// app/Validators/CustomValidator.php

<?php namespace App\Validators;

use App;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{
    public function validateExactLength($attribute, $values, $params)
    {
        return ($params[0] === strlen($values));
    }

}


// resources/lang/en/validation.php
"exact_length" => "The :attribute must be a :exact_length characters."
```

It works like charm and prints following message if it fails ...

> "myFieldName must be a **:exact_length** characters."

Notice above the bold char, i.e. it does not replace it with the value that I have provided in Validation Request file which is

> `app/Http/Requests/StoreSmsPriceRequest.php`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'MyFieldName' => 'required|exact_length:6'
    ];
}
```

So the problem is does not print the required length in the error message. How can do that?

Comment: Is your field a string or number? If its a string why don't you just use `'required|size:6'`

Comment: It can be anything(str or number). If it was only number I would have used `digits`?

Comment: Oh yes that is so silly of me I can use `size:value`. Thanks @jfadich. But just curious how can I solve above problem?